# RFC 5746 error when browsing web-page on my own server engine

Tags: winapi, firefox, rfc

I have my own server engine (like Apache). But when I browsing webpages based on this server engine in Firefox, I get error "Your server doesn't support RFC 5746".

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Fix the server.  A server claiming to implement SSL but not implementing RFC 5746 is insecure: it's SSL connections can be hijacked by a man-in-the-middle attacker.

For what it's worth, the abstract of RFC 5746 explains that.